# Trouble with ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to graph this implicit equation, but I am unable to do so as the plot produced is an empty grid. May I know how do I fix this problem? Thank you!

```
g = 9.81;
mu = 0.3;
r = 0.35;
eqn = g/(mu Sin[theta] + Cos[theta]) == 
  Sqrt[(mu^2 + 1)/(g^2 + w^4 r^2 (Sin[theta])^2)]
ContourPlot[eqn, {w, 0, 200}, {theta, -10, 10}]
```

Comment: Indeed an empty plot in view of `FindInstance[eqn, {w, theta}, Reals]` which results in `{}`.

Comment: `Plot3D[{g/(mu Sin[theta]+Cos[theta]), Sqrt[(mu^2+1)/(g^2+w^4 r^2 (Sin[theta])^2)]},{w,0,200},{theta,-10,10}]` and press and drag the mouse to change the orientation of the plot around to see the two expressions

Comment: @Bill hi, thank you so much for the solution, but may I ask why the expression is unable to be plotted in a 2D plot?

Comment: `ContourPlot[left==right,...]` is only going to plot the level where `left==right`. If you instead did `ContourPlot[left-right,...]` then it would show more than one contour and more than one level. If you read https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html including clicking on the orange Details and Options and reading what that shows then this might help.

Answer (score 2):

We calculate (LHS-RHS)^2 by `(SubtractSides[eqn] // First)^2` and found that its minimum is greater than 0.

```
g = 9.81;
mu = 0.3;
r = 0.35;
eqn = g/(mu Sin[theta] + Cos[theta]) == 
  Sqrt[(mu^2 + 1)/(g^2 + w^4 r^2 (Sin[theta])^2)]
NMinimize[{(SubtractSides[eqn] // First)^2, 
  0 <= w <= 200, -10 <= theta <= 10}, {w, theta}]
```

> `{88.2949, {w -> 200., theta -> 9.71633}}`

The minimum `88.2949` means that in the domain  `0 <= w <= 200, -10 <= theta <= 10`, the equation `eqn` can't hold.